# How to count pages in file docs ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to count the number of pages in a docs file,
There are many pages in a docs file, I want to count the number of pages in it to facilitate input.
Currently I only count the number of pages if it is a pdf file.

Do you know any technology or gem that can solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the `docsplit` gem. You can find the documentation [here](http://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/).

Gemfile:

```rb
gem docsplit
```

Then you should be able to retrieve the number of pages with:

```
Docsplit.extract_length('path/to/stooges.docx')
```

Or you could convert your document to PDF and return the number of pages with the method you already know. Using `docsplit-paperclip-processor`, find the documentation [enter link description here](https://github.com/tienle/docsplit-paperclip-processor).

Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'docsplit-paperclip-processor'
```

Then run `bundle install`. Then in your model:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :file,
                    :styles => {
                      :pdf => {
                        :format => "pdf",
                        :processors => [:docsplit_pdf]
                      }
                    }

end
```